# Variable Names based on Number in Character Position in R

Tags: r, stringr

I'm currently trying to change variable names based on the number in each position of the string.

```
variables <- c("X0.0.1", "X0.1.0", "X1.0.0", "X0.0.2", "X0.1.1", "X0.2.0", "X1.0.1", 
"X1.1.0", "X2.0.0", "X0.0.3", "X0.1.2", "X0.2.1", "X0.3.0", "X1.0.2", "X1.1.1", "X1.2.0", 
"X2.0.1","X2.1.0","X3.0.0")
```

Ideally, I'd have something similar to `"X0.0.1" = "x", "X0.1.0" = "y", "X1.0.0" = "z", "X0.0.2" = "xx"` is there a way to quickly duplicate the variable if there is a 2 in the position of that number? Or even `"X3.0.0" = "zzz"`?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the logic behind this task?

Comment: My hope is that I can order these variables alphabetically.

Comment: I understand the logic of all but `"X1"`. What is the expected output of this one?

Comment: I've removed `X1` as it is not necessary in this case.

Comment: What about row 15? Should that be "xzy"?

Comment: Ideally "xyz" for alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following code does what the question asks for. It uses `rep` to get the repetitions and then `paste` them together.

```
s <- strsplit(substring(variables, 2), "\\.")
sapply(s, function(x){
  vec <- c("x", "y", "z")[seq_along(x)]
  x <- as.integer(x)
  y <- rep(vec, rev(x))
  paste(y, collapse = "")
})
# [1] "x"   "y"   "z"   "xx"  "xy"  "yy"  "xz"  "yz"  "zz"  "xxx"
#[11] "xxy" "xyy" "yyy" "xxz" "xyz" "yyz" "xzz" "yzz" "zzz"
```

## Edit.

The following function tries to answer the dialog in the comments. It returns a data.frame with the strings and their degrees. Then it's a matter of sorting by `degree/chr`.

```
changeVariable <- function(x, chr = c("x", "y", "z")){
  s <- strsplit(substring(x, 2), "\\.")
  y <- lapply(s, function(.x){
    vec <- chr[seq_along(.x)]
    .x <- as.integer(.x)
    .y <- rep(vec, rev(.x))
    list(chr = paste(.y, collapse = ""),
         degree = sum(.x)
    )
  })
  res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, y)
  row.names(res) <- NULL
  res
}

res <- changeVariable(variables)
res[order(res$degree, res$chr), ]
```

## Edit 2.

With results pasted with superscripts:

```
changeVariable2 <- function(x){
  s <- strsplit(substring(x, 2), "\\.")
  y <- lapply(s, function(.x){
    vec <- c("x", "y", "z")[seq_along(.x)]
    .x <- rev(as.integer(.x))
    .y <- vec[.x != 0]
    .x <- .x[.x != 0]
    list(chr = paste0(.y, "^", .x, collapse = " "),
         degree = sum(.x)
    )
  })
  res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, y)
  row.names(res) <- NULL
  res
}
```

Comment: @statsguy27 Assign `variables <- sapply(etc)`.

Comment: Could you explain how the `y <- rep(vec, rev(x))` definition is working to determine the order of the variables? I can see that it is repeating `"x" "y" "z"` but how is it finding the order and correctly determining the variable name? Edit: it appears to be because of the nature of the variables, ex. `X0.0.1 = x`

Comment: @statsguy27 `x` is in reverse order (say, `"0.1.2"` means no `"z"`, 1 `"y"` and 2 `"x"`) so it must be reversed to get the names in correct order.

Comment: I see with the result "yy" comes before "xz", is it possible to order variables alphabetically within their "degree". For the second degree it would look something like `"xx"`, `"xy"`, `"xz"`, `"yy"`, `"yz"`, `"zz"`.

Comment: is it at all possible to to superscript the variables?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210808/discussion-between-statsguy27-and-rui-barradas).